# App not finding resources after locale change in Android

Tags: android, crash, resources, locale

I am working on a project which requires on the fly language changes. I am attempting to set the desired Locale but as soon as I do, the app crashes complaining that it cannot find Resources (things like R.layout.* R.drawable.*)

This is the code I am using to set the new Locale:

```
            String languageToLoad = "es";
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Edit: added log

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flavorburst.mcdonalds/com.flavorburst.mcdonalds.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.flavorburst.mcdonalds.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:106)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f08001e
            at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:451)
            at com.flavorburst.mcdonalds.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:91)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1673)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:854)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4717)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.flavorburst.application.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:106)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Post you stacktrace from LogCat.

Comment: As per your log, it looks like you have a problem with one or more of your resource files (strings.xml) at line 25. Check this line.

Comment: I think that line 25 is referring to the layout it is trying to inflate, not the strings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f08001e at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:451) at com.flavorburst.mcdonalds.NavigationDrawerFragment
```

refers to a string array that you have defined in one of your XML files, but you forgot to create the string array value in `/values/array.xml`. For example, in one of your XML files, you may have specified a string array value of "arrayNames", but you forgot to declare it in `/values/array.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="arrayNames"/>
</resources>
```

So, at runtime, the compiler will complain that it cannot find "arrayNames" in `/values/array.xml`. Hence, the error you got when you run your app.

Comment: That did it! I feel like a bit of an idiot. I had to make sure any/all of the files which contained strings,arrays,ect were in the  language folder. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, Daniel. Glad I could help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project? If you are using eclipse got to Project -> Clean. And then build again. If you are using Android Studio and gradle, type the following command line on a terminal:

```
./gradlew clean
```

or

use the Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: The application compiles and launches just fine. It is as if after the Locale is changed the application loses reference to the resources. Here is one example of the Error it spits out at crash: 

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f08001e

Comment: @DanielJackson: FYI - Application does not lose reference to resources. Maybe you define the Spanish (Locale "es") translation file incorrectly.

Comment: I suppose that you are using different files as it's proposed on the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework right? I.e: res/drawable-es/

Comment: @AlexiosKarapetsas I do not need different images for the languages I just need some string files done in different languages, and for those I have them in properly named folders I.e: res/values-en, res/values-es

Comment: @DanielJackson Can you please post the Fragment class? I suppose that there might be an initialization issue..